# IAM Role Created Through Cognito for EC2

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-iam, amazon-cognito

I created a new IAM role through Cognito during the setup process. Here is that policy:

```
{
"Version": "2012-10-17",
"Statement": [
    {
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": [
            "sns:publish"
        ],
        "Resource": [
            "*"
        ]
    }
]
```

}

In the trust relationship tab, it shows "The identity provider(s) cognito-idp.amazonaws.com" and it has a condition for sts:Externalid.

I tried adding a policy for FullEC2Access but so far I have not been able to get this IAM role to show up in the drodown when creating a new EC2 instance.

I will be using this instance for a new web app which will utilize Cognito. Any feedback appreciated.

Comment: Can you explain more about what you are trying to accomplish? Why do you think the Cognito role needs to be assigned to the EC2 instance?

Comment: I am pretty new to IAM, so I was trying to have a role for the EC2 instance to use Cognito. I assumed I have to use the role that Cognito created. My thought process is probably wrong in assuming that. Would I be better off having a role for EC2 on it's own that lets it access Cognito?

Comment: Yes you need to create an IAM Instance Profile, and assign it whatever roles the EC2 server will need to have. Then the Instance Profile will be available in the dropdown when you create a new EC2 instance. You need to create the profile, and associated roles, directly in the IAM console. You can assign any permissions from there.